# Exception when navigating to another page in Xamarin Forms using Prism and SignalR

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism, signalr.client

I have a Xamarin Forms PCL application using Prism.  Also, the application is a SignalR client.  In the MainPage (which the scaffolding creates) I setup SignalR:

```
 public MainPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        this.navigationService = navigationService;

        SetupSignalr();
    }

 private async void SetupSignalr()
    {
        hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://mypc:15816/");
        hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("SignatureCaptureHub");
        hubProxy.On<string>("ShowSignatureControl",  receiptText =>  NavigateToSignaturePad(receiptText));
        await hubConnection.Start();

        await hubProxy.Invoke("JoinGroup", "Group1234");
    }
```

This all works as intended.  The SignalR server gets the join group event.  My issue is with events received, i.e. the handler "NavigateToSignaturePad".  That handler looks as follows:

```
private async void NavigateToSignaturePad(string receiptText)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Got a ShowSignatureControl event!");

        Title = "Got a ShowSignatureControl event!";

        try
        {
            //Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => await navigationService.NavigateAsync("SignatureCapturePage"));
            await navigationService.NavigateAsync("SignatureCapturePage");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

As written I get the following exception when the signalR message is received:

> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod
>   (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo
>   method) [0x00068] in :0    at
>   Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallVoidMethod (System.IntPtr jobject,
>   System.IntPtr jmethod) [0x0000e] in
>   <9ab9faae1b4b4f0da28e7c4ac61e2c78>:0    at
>   Android.Views.IMenuInvoker.Clear () [0x00033] in
>   <9ab9faae1b4b4f0da28e7c4ac61e2c78>:0    at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer.UpdateMenu
>   () [0x0005a] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\NavigationPageRenderer.cs:682
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer.ToolbarTrackerOnCollectionChanged
>   (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs eventArgs) [0x00000] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\NavigationPageRenderer.cs:668
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Internals.ToolbarTracker.EmitCollectionChanged ()
>   [0x00008] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Internals\ToolbarTracker.cs:60
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Internals.ToolbarTracker.OnPropertyChanged
>   (System.Object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs
>   propertyChangedEventArgs) [0x00052] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Internals\ToolbarTracker.cs:130
>   at (wrapper delegate-invoke)
>   :invoke_void_object_PropertyChangedEventArgs
>   (object,System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs)   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.OnPropertyChanged (System.String
>   propertyName) [0x0000a] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:137
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Element.OnPropertyChanged (System.String
>   propertyName) [0x00000] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Element.cs:379
>   at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueActual
>   (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property,
>   Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+BindablePropertyContext context,
>   System.Object value, System.Boolean currentlyApplying,
>   Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+SetValueFlags attributes, System.Boolean
>   silent) [0x000f4] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:581
>   at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueCore
>   (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value,
>   Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+SetValueFlags attributes,
>   Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+SetValuePrivateFlags privateAttributes)
>   [0x0014b] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:378
>   at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValue
>   (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value,
>   System.Boolean fromStyle, System.Boolean checkAccess) [0x0005f] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:531
>   at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValue
>   (Xamarin.Forms.BindablePropertyKey propertyKey, System.Object value)
>   [0x0000e] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:91
>   at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.set_CurrentPage (Xamarin.Forms.Page
>   value) [0x00000] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\NavigationPage.cs:85
>   at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.PushPage (Xamarin.Forms.Page page)
>   [0x00011] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\NavigationPage.cs:371
>   at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage+d__90.MoveNext ()
>   [0x0002f] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\NavigationPage.cs:350
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage+d__48.MoveNext () [0x0017f] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\NavigationPage.cs:182
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   Prism.Navigation.PageNavigationService+d__31.MoveNext ()
>   [0x00139] in <7a32c28f35024e719a93e31b4d1e3d2a>:0 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   Prism.Navigation.PageNavigationService+<>c__DisplayClass17_0+<b__0>d.MoveNext () [0x00091] in <7a32c28f35024e719a93e31b4d1e3d2a>:0 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   Prism.Navigation.PageNavigationService+d__24.MoveNext
>   () [0x00125] in <7a32c28f35024e719a93e31b4d1e3d2a>:0 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   Prism.Navigation.PageNavigationService+d__17.MoveNext
>   () [0x00198] in <7a32c28f35024e719a93e31b4d1e3d2a>:0 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   Prism.Navigation.PageNavigationService+d__14.MoveNext
>   () [0x0016b] in <7a32c28f35024e719a93e31b4d1e3d2a>:0 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   ReceiptManager.SignatureCapture.ViewModels.MainPageViewModel+d__12.MoveNext
>   () [0x0005a] in
>   C:\Repos\ContentManagment.ReceiptManager.SignatureCapture\Source\ReceiptManager.SignatureCapture\ViewModels\MainPageViewModel.cs:65
>   --- End of managed Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException stack trace --- android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6556)     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:907)    at
>   android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:18722)  at
>   android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:18722)  at
>   android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:18722)  at
>   android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:18722)  at
>   android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:18722)  at
>   android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:18722)  at
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:360)
>     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:18722)     at
>   android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:18722)  at
>   android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:18722)  at
>   android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:18722)  at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:231)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchPresenterUpdate(MenuBuilder.java:284)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.onItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:1030)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.clear(MenuBuilder.java:589)

Why is it that the Title property (bound to a label on the MainPage) updates just fine, however, the navigation to another page throws a UI thread problem?

I tried to use the Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread method as well (commented out for reference), and the application crashes with an unhandled exception.

I am on version 2.3.3.192 of Xamarin.Forms using Visual Studio 2017 deploying to Android simulator.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue wasn't so much with Signalr's invocation of the handler, rather the view/page I was navigating to.  I had a binding to a TextCell in that view model and it seemed to be the main cause of the problem. I just used a label instead and the problem went away.  For reference here is the code I ended up  with:

```
 public MainPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        this.navigationService = navigationService;

        SetupSignalr();
    }

    private async void SetupSignalr()
    {
        hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://mypc:15816/");
        hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("SignatureCaptureHub");
        hubProxy.On<string>("ShowSignatureControl",  receiptText =>  NavigateToSignaturePad(receiptText));
        await hubConnection.Start();

        await hubProxy.Invoke("JoinGroup", "Group1234");
    }

    private void NavigateToSignaturePad(string receiptText)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Got a ShowSignatureControl event!");

        var navigationParameters = new NavigationParameters
        {
            { "receiptText", receiptText }
        };
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => navigationService.NavigateAsync(nameof(SignatureCapturePage), navigationParameters));
    }
```

I did have to use the BeginInvokeOnMainThread however. Without it, an exception was not thrown but the navigation did not happen either.